# 異なる名前空間に定義された同名のモデルのローディング

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

この質問は、異なる名前空間に定義された同名のモデルが実行時に期待したようにロードされないことに関する質問です。

Ruby on Rails 4で作ったアプリケーションで、私は投稿とカテゴリを表す2つのモデルを使っています。

```rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :category, required: true
end

class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts, dependent: :restrict_with_error
end
```

このアプリケーションは大きく分けて次の2つの画面を持っており、各モデルのパラメータに使う属性が異なります。

- **管理画面**: 変わらないURLを利用するために、モデルのパラメータに`id`を使う
- **一般画面**: わかりやすいURLを利用するために、モデルのパラメータに`name`を使う

この仕様を満たすために、私は各画面に対応する2つのMountable Engineでモデルを以下のように定義しました。

```rb
module Content
  class Post < ::Post
    def to_param
      name
    end
  end

  class Category < ::Category
    def to_param
      name
    end
  end
end

module Admin
  class Post < ::Post
  end

  class Category < ::Category
  end
end
```

さて、実際の振る舞いを確認してみます。私は以下のように`CategoriesController`でcategoryモデルに属するpostモデルのリンクを表示してみました。Content名前空間で実行しているため、パラメータはname属性になると私は期待しています。

しかし、パラメータがid属性になる時があったときがありました。この問題が難しい理由は、パラメータがname属性になる時もあったからです

```rb
module Content
  class CategoriesController < ApplicationController
    def show
      @category = Category.includes(:posts).find(params[:id])
    end
  end
end

ul
  - @category.posts.each do |post|
    li
      = link_to post.title, post
```

アプリケーションはdevelopment環境で実行しました。Rails Guidesの以下の章がヒントになるかと思いましたが、原因はわかりませんでした。

Autoloading and Reloading Constants
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html

なお、モデルのアソシエーションを名前空間で再定義する方法でこの問題を解決することも考えました。しかし、それはDRYでなく良い解決方法と感じています。

---

追記します。

同一のアクション/ビューで、どちらの結果になるときもあるということです。
全くのランダムかは、確かめる方法がないため分かりません。

実際のサンプルアプリケーションを以下にコミットしました。

https://github.com/lhside/namespace_app

ふと思い当たるふしがあり、Admin::Postを保存した直後にContent::PostsControllerのindexアクションにリクエストすると、id属性がパラメータとして表示されました。
その時のログは、先のリポジトリのREADMEにコピーしています。

Comment: 「パラメータはname属性になると私は期待」「パラメータがid属性になる時があった」のそれぞれ具体的なコードを示してください。質問にあるコードはどちらですか？

Comment: 似たような環境を作って再現しようとしましたが、提示されたコードだと、`= link_to post.title, post`は常にidのリンクになりました。`Content::Category`に`has_many :posts, class_name: 'Content::Post'`を定義すると、nameのリンクに変わりました。タイミングによってidやnameが切り替わるとのことですが、何か確実な再現手順はありますか？できればGitHub等に簡単なサンプルアプリをpushし、再現手順を提示してもらえると助かります。

Comment: @suzukis 質問にあるコードはlink_toメソッドの行です。link_toメソッドが生成するHTMLでパラメータがname属性になる場合とid属性になる場合がありました。

Comment: @lhside 同一のアクション/ビューで、どちらの結果になるときもあるということですか。全くのランダムなのでしょうか。何か条件に違いはありませんか。`name`になるときと`id`になるとき、それぞれのログなどはどうなっているでしょうか。(コメントではなく質問を編集して追記してください)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

サンプルアプリケーションのコミット、ありがとうございました。
手元でちょっとデバッグしてpull requestを作ってみました。

https://github.com/lhside/namespace_app/pull/1

修正ポイントは主に以下の2点です。

1. admin/app/models/category.rb を admin/app/models/admin/category.rb に移動
2. controller に require_dependency '...' を追加

```ruby
require_dependency 'admin/post'
module Admin
  class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @posts = Post.ordered
    end
    # ...
  end
end

require_dependency 'content/post'
module Content
  class PostsController < ApplicationController
    def index
      @posts = Post.ordered
    end
    # ...
  end
end
```

特に重要なのは require_dependency の方です。
この説明は以下のページに書いてあります。

[10.6 When Constants aren't Missed](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#when-constants-aren-t-missed)

> That code depends on the execution path.
>   These kind of ambiguities can often be resolved using qualified constants:

```
module BellX1
  class Plane
    def flight_model
      @flight_model ||= BellX1::FlightModel.new
    end
  end
end
```

> Also, require_dependency is a solution:

```
require_dependency 'bell_x1/flight_model'

module BellX1
  class Plane
    def flight_model
      @flight_model ||= FlightModel.new
    end
  end
end
```

上のように、Rails Guidesでは「明示的にネームスペース付きのクラス名にする方法」と「require_dependencyを使う方法」の2パターンが紹介されていますが、今回は後者を使ってみました。

簡単に説明すると、::Post は読み込まれているが Content::Post はまだ読み込まれていない状態で Content::PostsController にアクセスすると、コード中の Post が Content::Post ではなく、 ::Post として解釈されるのが原因です。
なので、 require_dependency 'content/post' を使って、強制的に Content::Post を読み込んでいます。
こうすると同じモジュール内の Post （つまり Content::Post）が使われるようになります。

実際のアプリケーションでも試してみてください。

Comment: 求めていた回答が得られました、ありがとうございます。require_dependencyで明示的に宣言できることを知ることができて良かったです。

Comment: お役に立ったようで良かったです。もしこれで問題が解決したのであれば回答の承認（緑のチェックマークを付ける）をお願いします。理由についてはこちらの記事を参考にしてください。 [問題が解決したら、回答を承認しましょう](http://blog.jnito.com/entry/2015/10/04/073825#問題が解決したら回答を承認しましょう)